# .htacess need help for removal of multiple dots in urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, isapi

I am looking to redirect a url but its giving error, we are using ISAPI on our windows server
This is the url i am trying to redirect, but its not redirecting. the problem is multiple dots.

```
RewriteRule ^keyword1/2\.\.?$ http://www.domain.com/keyword/21212.htm [R=301]
```

in the above instance it is not escaping the dots

The other url I am having issue is

```
RewriteRule ^keyword1/2\.\.\./Product/21.htm http://www.domain.com/keyword/21212.htm [R=301]
```

I have again used escape characters for this one, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please Help

Comment: What are the urls you want changed? `keyword1/2..` and `keyword1/2.../Product21.htm`?

Comment: Hi Howlin.. 
Basically I want to change /keyword/...abc.../100.htm to /keyword/100.htm and /keyword.../100.htm to /keyword/100.htm

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the `...` from the url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^keyword.../(.*)$ /keyword/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^keyword/(.*)/(.*)$ /keyword/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

EDIT: Try this

```
RewriteRule ^bathroom-furniture-shower-taps/2...$ /bathroom-furniture-shower-taps/22456.htm [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @howling Thanks for answering 
tried your code but its not working.

RewriteRule ^keyword/2.../(.*)$ /keyword/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Can you provide an example link you are using? `http://example.com....` You have changed the url a few times there...

Comment: Is it only that link?

Comment: I have edited my post, it should work for the url you posted.